# Does anyone have the Microsoft Windows Mobile Battery Icons?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

### Microsoft's Windows Mobile Icons

I've got a few projects that make nice use of these very basic Windows Mobile icons:

[image: Windows Mobile GUI]

Within the last 2 years, I have swapped PCs. I just learned that the image files I used for these icons were not copied over.

Yes, I know I could recreate some cheesy or overly flashy icons, but I like the simplicity and universal understanding of the ones I found that have an International Standards look.

- Does anyone have these?
- Does anyone know where to get these?
- Does anyone know how I can extract these icons from my existing `ImageList` so I can use them in other projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I found them in the Device's own `Windows` folder!

Here are all of the files I needed (plus some) with the path to the file as well as the actual image itself.

If someone else needs this, too, just right click the image and select "Save As":

- [image: battery.bmp] **Path** `Windows\battery.bmp`
- [image: battery_alert.bmp] **Path** `Windows\battery_alert.bmp`
- [image: batteryCharging.bmp] **Path** `Windows\batteryCharging.bmp`
- [image: batteryNone.bmp] **Path** `Windows\batteryNone.bmp`
- [image: No_Signal.bmp] **Path** `Windows\No_Signal.bmp`
- [image: radioconnected.bmp] **Path** `Windows\radioconnected.bmp`
- [image: radioOff.bmp] **Path** `Windows\radioOff.bmp`
- [image: WIFI_on.bmp] **Path** `Windows\WIFI_on.bmp`

So, the question is answered.

**However**, I'll donate a +1 to every other answer myself that adds more standard Windows Mobile (Pocket PC, WM5, or WM6) icons to this page. Hopefully, others will +1 your donations, too.